# How to select id previously created in JQuery/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have table created dynamically after AJAX return call. Once table is built I need to update one of the elements. If I use JQuery selector to get the value for specified ID I see `undefined` in my Developer tools. Here is example of my table:

```
var tbl = "<table class='tblData' id='tblMater'><caption id='numRec'>Records: "+numRecs+"</caption><thead><tr><th>Code</th><th>Sort Order</th><th>Name</th><th>Comment</th><th>Active</th><th>Edit</th><th>Delete</th></tr></thead><tbody>";

for(var i=0; i < numRecs; i++){
    var jsRec = obj.DATA[i];
    //Here I build td elements
}
tbl += "</tbody></table></div>";
```

Here is example of function where I test JQuery selector:

```
function Test(){
  console.log($('#numRec').val()); //I have tried getElementById() as well.
}
```

As I mentioned above I see undefined in my Console. If anyone knows the way how I can get the value from my table element please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: table elements don't have value, so it makes no sense to access `.val()`. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Taplar Table gets created first. I run test() function after that. All I need is to pull number of Records from my caption tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`val()` returns the value="" of an element.  If you want the text of the node you want to use `html()` or `text()` instead.

Further more, if you want *just* the number, i'd suggest putting a span around it that you can specifically target before doing so.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$("#numRec").text();
```